# Custom Cell Click Fires When Clicked Twice Issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, modalviewcontroller

I've two custom cell in a `tableview` one of them is pushing to another viewController while the other is modal to another viewController. Once I click on the second cell that modal to the viewController nothing happen but if I click again on the screen in any place the modal viewController comes.

I've enabled the cell in the storyboard without coding. So please where would be my issue?

CustomCell Code:

H.

```
@interface CustomCellAboutUs : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *AboutUsLbl;

@end
```

M.

```
#import "CustomCellAboutUs.h"

@implementation CustomCellAboutUs

- (void)awakeFromNib {
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}
@end
```

MainView Controller:

M.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if( indexPath.row == 0 ) {

    CustomCell01 *customCellimg = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell01"];

    customCellimg.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"];

    customCellimg.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return customCellimg;
}

else if (indexPath.row == 4) {

    CustomCellAboutUs *customCellAboutUs = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCellAboutUs"];

    customCellAboutUs.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    customCellAboutUs.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"nudeSideBarEmpty.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];

    customCellAboutUs.AboutUsLbl.text = @"About Us";

    return customCellAboutUs;
}

else {

    CustomCell0 *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell0"];

    customCell.lblSlide.text = [searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"nudeSideBarEmpty.png"]]; //set image for UITableView

    customCell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"nudeSideBarEmpty.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];

    customCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return customCell;
  }
}

   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tbl1 indexPathForCell:sender];

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomCell0";

    CustomCell0 *customCell = [_tbl1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    customCell.lblSlide.text = [searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *newString = [customCell.lblSlide.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" -" withString:@""];

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TESTTEST"]) {

    UINavigationController *navController = segue.destinationViewController;

    ViewController *destViewController = [navController childViewControllers].firstObject;

    destViewController.str1 = str;
    destViewController.subjectNameSupplier = newString;
  }
}
```

Comment: show your `code` for clear understanding

Comment: Feel free to let us understand how you implemented the custom `UITableViewCells`

Comment: It seems problem is in `Selecting Row (didSelectRowAtIndexpath)`, add that `code` too, it would be helpful.

Comment: @arthankamal I'm using segue and I have deleted all segue code but it is still doing the same issue. Code added